# Can a menu item appear dimmed (not removed) in S60?

Tags: symbian, s60

In Symbian S60 (not QT), if a menu item is not applicable to my current menu state, can I make it appear but greyed out, or is it always removed from the menu (i.e. invisible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symbian S60, CEikMenuPane::SetItemDimmed() removes menu options.

In the now defunct Symbian UIQ, the same function dimmed/greyed out menu options.

[See this book.](http://books.google.com/books?id=Yh8Yosl04doC&lpg=PA67&ots=STHUdMWwg0&dq=SetItemDimmed%20uiq&hl=en&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q=SetItemDimmed%20uiq&f=false)

So just use that function and have them removed in Symbian 60 (which has merged and is just called Symbian nowadays).

Answer (score 0):

I never saw this in past 8yrs I am developing on Symbian, the item is always hidden. I had made custom menu on my own - but I cannot advice this approach. With Symbian source code I could probably hack it for your application, but the effort will not be paid back.

BR
STeN